# User Creation Flow via API

Tags: okta, okta-api

I'm creating a user in 2 parts; firstly without creds and and then when the user clicks on an email link (with code) we then get them to put in the password and recover q&a. I'm then using the APIs to finish and activate the user in this order:
setPassword
setRecoveryQuestion
activateUser

When i check the user they're ACTIVE but when i try and log in the UI challenges me to select a picture, recovery answer etc.

What's the correct order/way to complete a user created w/o credentials so that they only need to use their username and password?

Comment: Can you provide the example API calls you are making.

Comment: Thomas,

the calls i'm using are these (via the java API):


client.setRecoveryQuestion(userId, question, answer);

then

client.setPassword(userId, userPassword);


then finally

client.activateUser(userId);

All straightforward but for some reason when i then login to the OKTA dashboard it presents me with a screen requesting the answer to the security question and to select a picture.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to configure the [MFA policy](https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/27315047-Configuring-Multifactor-Authentication) to not require security image/picture.